# Reduce the height of a telerik graph chart

Tags: objective-c, xcode, telerik, telerik-grid

I am creating a graph chart using telerik TChart. Using storyboard I set the position of a graphview.

For iPhone,it's height is correct for all values of chart but for Ipad if I give maximum value it will touch the above labels. so I have to reduce the height of that view of chart programmatically.

Is there any way to reduce the height of graph.If I want to set frame size height of graph using

`_graphView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`

it will generate exception. so is there any other way to set height.

Comment: Is there any one who are using telerik to create a graph?..... or give any suggetioc which framework are now popular to create chart  and send me some example and link to create a line graph using that.... for this thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no one, who are using telerik to create graph in ios